# date and time not being added to table with correct default and datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, timestamp, default

I am using AnySQL Maestro  13.2.0.15 which is SQL-server based. I need the date and time to automatically be put in the column "added" of my table called "accntgs" with out me having to select the current date and time. I have added the field with the datetime data type and set the default to getdate(), but then when I enter a new record and post it, the added field is still null. I have also tried to use the timestamp data type, and when I post a new record with that, the added field says (bytes) and does not have the date or the time. How do I fix this and get the date and time the record is posted to show up.

I have also tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE accntgs ADD CONSTRAINT
DF_accntgs_added DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR added
```

and it didnt add the the date when the new record was posted either

Comment: How you inserting to the table?  Does the insert explicitly set `DF_accntgs_added` to null?

Comment: Is that column defined as NOT NULL? If the column allows NULL it will not use the default.

Comment: @SeanLange it is not null and it says "multiple-step operation generated errors. check each status value"

Comment: @DStanley i am inserting directly into the table by clicking the plus button at the top of the table that says "insert"

Comment: I don't know anything about "AnySQL Maestro" but it sounds like it's inserting a explicit value rather then leaving that column out and letting SQL use the default.  If you specify the column and a value in the `INSERT` the default value will not be used.

Comment: Also note that the `timestamp` data time is not directly translatable to a `DateTime` - it is just meant to represent a unique number that can be used to know _if_ a record has been changed (not _when_).

Comment: @DStanley yeah, im leaving that column blank then it gives me that error when i try to post the entry. and all that matters is that ill be able to sort the records in order of when they were added or edited. will timestamp do this even though i cant see a specific date/time?

Comment: It sounds like something specific to the AnySQL Maestro application. I have never used it and know nothing about it.

Comment: @samhatcher yes `timestamp` (which is deprecated - you should use [`rowversion`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) now) should increase whenever a row is added or edited.  It sounds like you just need to get AnySQL to ignore that column when updating/inserting since the DB will update it for you.

Comment: @DStanley but if i use rowversion, wont all the rows that have only been edited once or not edited ever have the same value and therefore not sort according to when they were added to the database?

Comment: @samhatcher No.  `rowversion` and `timestamp` are the same in MS-SQL.  `timestamp` is a deprecated alias for `rowversion`.  They should work exactly the same.

Comment: i bet if you do a profiler trace, as @Sean said, an explicit value is being inserted into the column.